# mysql bulk table script execution

Tags: mysql, performance, execute

I have 120 tables in my project.

Now I have to migrate **MSSQL** to **MySQL**.

So I did all Queries to create those tables that are already worked.

Now my problem is when I execute this script in **MSSQL** it completes ***within a second***.

But **MySQL** takes ***around 4 min*** to complete its execution.

I want to improve my performance in **MySQL**. But I don't know how to do that if anyone knows please help me.

Thank you

Here is my sample table Script

**MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE `rb_tbl_bak` (
  `BakPathId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `BakPath` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `BakDate` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BakPathId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

**MSSQL**

```
--Create table and its columns
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RB_Tbl_Bak] (
    [BakPathId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [BakPath] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [BakDate] [datetime] NULL);
GO
```

like this way, I have to complete for 120+ tables

Comment: What is in the "script"?  Table creation?  Inserts?  Any Selects?  _Give us some clue of that to focus on!_

Comment: its a table creation Script

Comment: Bash script?  Table named `Script`?  An application named `Script`?  Something else?  Or maybe that is the name of the migration program?

Comment: Script means it contains tables structures like **Create table [tbl_name]**  and Pls check my sample table struct in the above edited question

Comment: @RickJames he probably mean a SQL File, with all create statement. It should not take 4 minute to create 120 tables, I often create 30-40 tables in less than seconds. So it must be your mysql is not optimized properly within itself. It will be better if you share script or at least tell us version of mysql and what hardware you are using.

Comment: Also, since migration is onetime, what difference it make to run in 4 minute? Or you want to do it again and again.

Comment: I am using MySQL server and MySQL workbench version 8.0.26. Also my hardware specification is **Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz   3.40 GHz** Processor **16GB** RAM and win10 as OS

Comment: I don't know how to share my script file to you. Can you please tell me the way to share file.

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, In this case, MySQL databases take time.

You can turn on [profiling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profile.html) to get an idea of what takes so long. An example is given using Mysql's CLI:-

```
SET profiling = 1;
CREATE TABLE rb_tbl_back (id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
SET profiling = 1;
```

You should get a response like this:-

```
mysql> SHOW PROFILES;
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 0.00913800 | CREATE TABLE rb_tbl_back (id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000071 |
| checking permissions | 0.000007 |
| Opening tables       | 0.001698 |
| System lock          | 0.000043 |
| creating table       | 0.007260 |
| After create         | 0.000004 |
| query end            | 0.000004 |
| closing tables       | 0.000015 |
| freeing items        | 0.000031 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000002 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000003 |
+----------------------+----------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you read the profiling documentation, there are other flags for showing the profile of the query CPU, BLOCK IO, etc that might help you on the 'creating table' stage.

I got this answer from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/mysql-table-creation-insanely-slow/27813#27813)

Comment: Thank you. I will check that documentation

Comment: Welcome, I wish it solve your problem 

Comment: 9.1ms for do `CREATE TABLE`.  That is reasonable if using HDD.  (It seems quite slow for SSD.)  Since `CREATE TABLE` is a one-time task, I don't see it as being an issue in the "grand scheme of things".